# BigQuery query invalidly returning "No Results" when using "Not In" clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I spent some time and resources running and verifying a simple query in BigQuery which gave me zero results. I know for sure though that this query should give me results, so I wonder why this is occurring and whether it's swallowing some kind of error.
I know it seems more likely that I made a mistake in my query, but I checked this multiple times with different people and really do not see where my mistake could possibly be.

We have our table *audit_v3.mutations* which contains around 25 billion audit records. 
These records have a required field *sourceId* and a required field called *deltaStatus* which can have the values "new", "stale" or "delta".

Functionally we wouldn't expect it to be possible that there are "stale" records for a given sourceId without there being "new" records, but we did find some occurrences of this, for example

```sql
SELECT
  deltaStatus
FROM
  `project.audit_v3.mutations`
WHERE
  sourceId = '497786711'
```

Results in:

```
stale
stale
stale
stale
stale
stale
```

But when we wanted to check how often this occurs in total:

```sql
SELECT
  sourceId
FROM
  `project.audit_v3.mutations`
WHERE
  WHERE deltaStatus = "stale"
  AND sourceId NOT IN (
  SELECT
    sourceId
  FROM
    `project.audit_v3.mutations`
  WHERE
    deltaStatus = "new" )
```

This query results in ***No Results***, even though we *know* it should at least return sourceId '497786711'.

My guess is that the query actually fails somewhere underwater because the "not in" clause is too big, but I would've expected an error as the result instead of "No results". For reference, there are 23 billion "new" records and 1.5 billion "stale".

As a workaround it did work to run the queries on "stale" and "new" separately and store them in their own tables.

Comment: Have you tried the query on a small dataset with equal schema definitions to compare? (I have no clue about bigquery, I just assume this is possible)

Comment: @findusl Yes, and that works fine. Also running the queries separately worked properly, I'll add that to the question

Comment: Consider refactoring your queries to take advantage of JOINs.  Create CTEs for distinct 'stale' IDs and distinct 'new' IDs and then LEFT JOIN to find IDs where 'stale' exists and 'new' does not.